# Passing data to refresh_view_attrs. Python. Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How can I pass `data` from `RequestRecycleView` to `refresh_view_data`? I tried with global variables and instantiating `data` in `RequestRecycleView` but still can't trigger `refresh_view_data` by appending Observable `data`. It is working when I return `RequestRecycleView` as root but I want `ScreenManager` to be my root.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior


kv = """
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
ScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    RequestsScreen:

<RequestRow@BoxLayout>

    size_hint_y: None
    orientation: 'vertical'
    row_index: id_row_index.text
    row_index:''
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    Label:
        id: id_row_index 
        text: root.row_index


<RequestRecycleView@RecycleView>:               
    #id: rv
    viewclass: 'RequestRow'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True

<RequestsScreen>
    name: 'RequestsScreen'
    BoxLayout:         
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label: 
            text: 'recycle'
        RequestRecycleView:


"""

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''



class RequestRow(RecycleDataViewBehavior):
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''

        self.index = index
        self.row_index = str(index)
        self.row_content = data['text']
        return super(RequestRow, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class RequestRecycleView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = []
        for r in range(30):
            row = {'text': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6))}
            self.data.append(row)

class RequestsScreen(Screen):
    pass

Builder.load_string(kv)

sm = ScreenManagement()
sm.add_widget(RequestsScreen(name = 'requests'))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modifying

```
<RequestRow@BoxLayout>

    size_hint_y: None
    orientation: 'vertical'
    row_index: id_row_index.text
    row_index:''
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    Label:
        id: id_row_index 
        text: root.row_index
```

to

```
<RequestRow@BoxLayout>
    text: 'abba'
    size_hint_y: None
    orientation: 'vertical'
    row_index: id_row_index.text
    row_index:''
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    Label:
        id: id_row_index 
        text: self.parent.text
```

results in working code. Note that the dictionary keys in the `data` are expected to be attributes of the `viewclass`. The added `text` attribute in `RequestRow`, provides that attribute, and the `text: self.parent.text` in the `Label` places that text (from the `viewclass`) into the `Label`. Also, you can replace the lines:

```
Builder.load_string(kv)

sm = ScreenManagement()
sm.add_widget(RequestsScreen(name = 'requests'))
```

with just:

```
sm = Builder.load_string(kv)
```

since your `kv` file specifies the `ScreenManager` as the root object.